# Python and SQLite3 - Select Where not working inside script but works in console

Tags: python, sqlite

As the title says, I'm having problems retrieving data from a SQLite DB when using WHERE statement.

Here is the piece of code that tries to get a row where an ID is given:

```
def check_attendance(self, cred):
    query = """SELECT * FROM clients WHERE dni=?"""
    self.conn.cursor().execute(query, (cred,))
    record = self.conn.cursor().fetchone()
```

The var **cred** is already inside a tuple as specified by SQLite API for Python. Sadly, the query returns **None** when executed here.

If I do the same but using sqlite.exe, then I do get the right row back. In fact, this is the only query I cannot execute properly from my python script, everything else return rows normally.

[Here it is executing from the Python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq7JI.png)

[And here is in sqlite.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncffq.png)

Here is the piece that stores values in the DB:

```
def new_client(self, *args):
    success = False
    # Check if all inputs are filled
    if self.dialog.content_cls.ids.user_name.text and self.dialog.content_cls.ids.user_surname.text and len(self.dialog.content_cls.ids.user_dni.text) == 8 and self.dialog.content_cls.ids.user_date.text:
        # Convert str date to a datetime obj in order to use it with timedelta
        paid_date = datetime.strptime(self.dialog.content_cls.ids.user_date.text, "%d-%m-%Y")
        # paid_date is now YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS format

        # Add 30 days to paid_date
        exp_date = paid_date + timedelta(days=30)

        # Convert YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-DD to string YYYY-MM-DD as we don't need clock
        paid_date = datetime.strptime(str(paid_date), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        exp_date = datetime.strptime(str(exp_date), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        # Create query blueprint and try executing
        query = """INSERT INTO clients (name, surname, dni, membership_date, expiration_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"""
        try:
            self.conn.execute(query, (self.dialog.content_cls.ids.user_name.text,
                                      self.dialog.content_cls.ids.user_surname.text,
                                      self.dialog.content_cls.ids.user_dni.text,
                                      paid_date,
                                      exp_date
                                      )
                              )
            success = True
        except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
            pass
        if success:
            self.conn.commit()
```

The try/except was used for other reasons. Adding to the database from the Python script works fine as shown in the second screenshot.

And the table clients is as follows:

```
    c.execute(''' CREATE TABLE clients (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
                                        name TEXT NOT NULL,
                                        surname TEXT NOT NULL,
                                        dni INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                                        membership_date date NOT NULL,
                                        expiration_date date NOT NULL); ''')
```

Using Python v3.7.7 32bit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the cursor is initialized two times (cursor()).

You should either get the results from the same cursor you used to execute the SELECT statement:

```
def check_attendance(self, cred):
    query = """SELECT * FROM clients WHERE dni=?"""
    cur = self.conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(query, (cred,))
    record = cur.fetchone()
```

...or you can avoid the implicit cursor creation by using execute method directly on Connection object:

```
def check_attendance(self, cred):
    query = """SELECT * FROM clients WHERE dni=?"""
    record = self.conn.execute(query, (cred,)).fetchone()
```

You can read more about this approach in the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-sqlite3-efficiently):

> Using the nonstandard execute(), executemany() and executescript() methods of the Connection object, your code can be written more concisely because you don’t have to create the (often superfluous) Cursor objects explicitly. Instead, the Cursor objects are created implicitly and these shortcut methods return the cursor objects.